# InputStream returns 0 with HttpUrlConnection in Android

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

I'm doing a `HttpUrlConnection` in Android application with an `URL`. The `URL` is giving me response in the browser but in the code below `InputStream` response is `0`. Why?

Here's my code:

```
URL url = new URL("https://certify.securenet.com/payment.scrnt");

HttpURLConnection httpCon = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
InputStream in = httpCon.getInputStream();

byte content[] = new byte[in.available()];
in.read(content, 0, content.length);
String receivedString = new String(content);
Log.d("Received String", receivedString)
```

Comment: Your question is really not clear.  What isn't working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing from "https://" to "http://" in the URL if you don't need a secure connection.
Or try changing to HttpsUrlconnection instead of HttpUrlconnection.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you have to use `HttpsUrlConnection` for URLs with **https** scheme.